# get data spread/stddev from singular value decomposition with weighted least squares

Tags: math, linear-algebra, least-squares, svd

I have a scalarfield which has been discretized into a grid of voxels. I am trying to fit a specific 3d function to that scalarfield. The 3d function I want to fit is defined by a plane and a gaussian fall-off per distance to that plane. Just to be clear: I am not talking about fitting a plane surface to a scalarfield but about fitting a 3d function defined by a plane and a fall-off (kind of a fuzzy plane or a band).

So far I managed to find the plane parameters. I do this by plugging all voxel positions and their scalar values of the input field into a weighted least squares problem. I am roughly following this procedure here: [Weighted least square - fit a plane to 3D point set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243645/weighted-least-square-fit-a-plane-to-3d-point-set). The difference is that my point set consists of all the voxel centers weighted by their respective input scalarfield values. It seems to work pretty well and I am getting nice reasonable plane parameters.

My question now is about finding the standard deviation for my gaussian fall-off function. What is interesting is that the singular values from SVD actually relate to the spread of the data in the local coordinate system of the plane. This relationship has been discussed here: [Can I get data spread (noise) from singular value decomposition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154950/can-i-get-data-spread-noise-from-singular-value-decomposition). The difference to my problem is that I am working with a weighted least squares problem and when I divide the singular values by the square root of the weighted sum, my standard deviation is roughly doing the right thing but still is quite off.

I basically would like to know if there is a formal relationship between the singular values of a SVD and the standard deviation of samples from a plane given by a weighted least squares fit. In particular, can I expect to be able to exactly reconstruct the plane and standard deviation parameter when the input scalarfield has been created from such a parameterization?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Ahh, I think this question would get more useful answers on http://math.stackexchange.com?